# Python, pillow grab not load the images frames correctly

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

I'm trying to use `pillow.grab` to get frames of my screen. For later detect objects for every frame.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab as ig
import time


# Load Yolo
net = cv2.dnn.readNet("yolov3_training_last.weights", "yolov3_testing.cfg")

# Name custom object
classes = ["amongus"]

layer_names = net.getLayerNames()
output_layers = [layer_names[i[0] - 1] for i in net.getUnconnectedOutLayers()]
colors = np.random.uniform(0, 255, size=(len(classes), 3))

last_time = time.time()
while(True):
    img_ = ig.grab(bbox=None)
    
    open_cv_image = np.array(img_) 
    open_cv_image = open_cv_image[:, :, ::-1].copy() 
    
    img = cv2.resize(open_cv_image, None, fx=0.4, fy=0.4)
    height, width, channels = img.shape

    # Detecting objects
    blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(img, 0.00392, (416, 416), (0, 0, 0), True, crop=False)

    net.setInput(blob)
    outs = net.forward(output_layers)

    # Showing informations on the screen
    class_ids = []
    confidences = []
    boxes = []
    for out in outs:
        for detection in out:
            scores = detection[5:]
            class_id = np.argmax(scores)
            confidence = scores[class_id]
            if confidence > 0.3:
                # Object detected
                print(class_id)
                center_x = int(detection[0] * width)
                center_y = int(detection[1] * height)
                w = int(detection[2] * width)
                h = int(detection[3] * height)

                # Rectangle coordinates
                x = int(center_x - w / 2)
                y = int(center_y - h / 2)

                boxes.append([x, y, w, h])
                confidences.append(float(confidence))
                class_ids.append(class_id)

    indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.5, 0.4)
    print(indexes)
    font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN
    for i in range(len(boxes)):
        if i in indexes:
            x, y, w, h = boxes[i]
            label = str(classes[class_ids[i]])
            color = colors[class_ids[i]]
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), color, 2)
            #cv2.putText(img, label, (x, y + 30), font, 3, color, 2)


    cv2.imshow("Image", np.array(img_))
    #key = cv2.waitKey(0)

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

If I uncomment the `#key = cv2.waitKey(0)` works because I'm taking just one frame for every time I press a key, but once I comment that part, I got this screen.

[image]

I'm assuming (not sure at all if it's because of that) that this is happening because a lot of frames are coming, but if I `sleep(n)` the while fps will be so low. (I guess?)

What's happening / how to fix it?

Comment: Try `cv2.waitKey(1)` or `cv2.waitKey(20)`.

Comment: Now it works perfectly, but the fps are sooo low, any suggestion?

Comment: You'll need to do better than saying it is slow! How slow? Slow compared to what? What speed were you expecting? What are you running on - a single core Raspberry Pi Zero, or a 32-core macOS workstation? How big are your frames? How long does the acquisition take? How long does the CNN take?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, each iteration of the whole while loop takes like 0.07 seconds on average, running in Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-9700K CPU @ 3.60GHz   3.60 GHz, 2070RTX. If by how big my frames are you mean the resolution, the screen resolution is 2560x1440 but for the last example I didn't get the whole screen but like 1/4 of my screen. I'm kinda new in this, so I'm sorry, I'm also sorry for my bad english, thanks for your comments!